# Why is Kryptonite lethal to Superman?

Tags: superman

I've been a fan of Superman for decades and I've always wondered why would a piece of his planet be lethal to him?

Am I misunderstanding the significance of what Kryptonite is?

Comment: I think that's something everyone has wondered at some point, I know I have and I have been a fan too. I know there are different kinds and they each have a different effect, so it could be that if taken down to its individual components they can have bad effects. Think we have arsenic in the ground and our rice but we don't die, but refine that and put in us and we go caput. Just a thought, not saying I know.

Comment: Related: (Science Fiction & Fantasy SE) [What actually happens to Superman when he is exposed to kryptonite?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42624/7957) |  [Why, exactly, does kryptonite hurt Superman?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80755/7957)

Comment: To which movie are you referring? If you mean the total breadth of comics, etc, then asking in [scifi.se] would be recommended.

Comment: One of the typical parts of his origin story is that as Krypton exploded the resulting debris was rendered radioactive. Over the years different, plot-convenient, varieties of Kryptonite were introduced.

Comment: I was referring particularly to the 1978 Superman (Christopher Reeves).  But the other group would probably be more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer, radiations.

Long answer,

> Kryptonite is a fictional material that appears primarily in Superman stories. In its best-known form, it is a green, crystalline material originating from Superman's home world of Krypton that emits a unique radiation that weakens Superman, but is generally harmless to humans when exposed to it in the short term but deadly in the long term.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite)

Think of it as, what happens if humans are exposed to radioactive materials eg uranium, plutonium.

Comment: This makes sense.  I always thought that Kryptonite should simply remove his powers and revert him back to a Kryptonian as if on his planet, with no powers.  Like humans.  I never thought it would be lethal.

Comment: @KingWilder: Every superhero has weakness except Deadpool. :-D